# sorting tuples in a list according to another self-made order

Tags: python, list, tuples

i'm having trouble sorting tuples within a list according to an order that I made up, represented in a list.  below is my tuples within my list

```
list_tup = [('NYC','SF'), ('HOU','BOS'), ('NYC','DAL')]
```

here is the order of elements, from start to finish, that i desire.  i put them in a list.

```
sls = ['SF','DAL','NYC','HOU', 'BOS']
```

i tried something basic like:

```
sorted(list_tup, key = sls)
```

but since list objects aren't callable, it doesn't work.  is it possible to do something like this?

my desired output would be:

```
output = [('SF','NYC'),('HOU','BOS'),('DAL','NYC')]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_tup = [('NYC', 'SF'), ('HOU', 'BOS'), ('NYC', 'DAL')]
sls = ['SF', 'DAL', 'NYC', 'HOU', 'BOS']

# Convert `sls` to a dictionary with the index as the value
sls_d = {item:idx for idx, item in enumerate(sls)}

# Sort individual tuples based on the index from `sls_d`
print [tuple(sorted(items, key=sls_d.get)) for items in list_tup]
# [('SF', 'NYC'), ('HOU', 'BOS'), ('DAL', 'NYC')]
```

If you are not worried about the performance, you can use the index of the elements in the `sls` list to sort, (the index lookup will be a linear search)

```
print [tuple(sorted(items, key=sls.index)) for items in list_tup]
# [('SF', 'NYC'), ('HOU', 'BOS'), ('DAL', 'NYC')]
```

Comment: awesome- i thought that a dictionary was the way to go.  just for my own curiosity, is it possible to do it with a list?  i'm guessing no

Comment: rly?  so how would it know the order without a dictionary?  for instance when i do:  print [tuple(sorted(key=sls))] it says list not iterable

Comment: @user2989523 Wait, I misunderstood you there. Could you please show some sample input?

Comment: basically to complete the above input and get the desired output by using a list instead of converting it to a dictionary with index as value.  ['SF', 'DAL', 'NYC', 'HOU', 'BOS'] would be the desired order of the list.  i'm guessing its not possible, was just wondering though

Comment: @user2989523 That is what the second method I have mentioned in the answer, please check the `key=sls.index` version.

Comment: ahh - wow - i have to do a better job of reading the complete answer haha - very interesting, thanks!